# Lexicographically minimal string rotation

Tags: strings

In this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation there is the Booth's Algorithm for lexicographically minimal string rotation but there is no proof. I can't access to article(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019080901490?via%3Dihub), can someone put here the proof? 
Maybe also here: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/applied-combinatorics-on-words/C64AAEDFA9A2EFE97671453EADE29E6C there is something on this argument.

Comment: Actually, the second book is available online without having to "sail the high seas": https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%25E9matiques/Fichiers%2520Claude/Auteurs/aaaDivers/Lothaire%2520-%2520Algebraic%2520Combinatorics%2520On%2520Words.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj6uN2x4YvnAhWDs3EKHWK_CoEQFjAMegQICxAB&usg=AOvVaw2dTUH72FAcpU918OXasxHz

Comment: Thank you very much.